# Fadein image after a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have followed [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/38Afs/) fiddle and created my own code but it is actually showing the image without a delay. Please guide.

```
<img class="delayImg" style="width:156px;margin: 41px 0; height:37px;opacity:0px;" delayedSrc="logo_new.png"  />

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delayImg").each(function() {
        this.onload = function() {
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 4000);
        };
        this.src = this.getAttribute("delayedSrc");
    });
});
```

Comment: There's no delay programmed in at all. Which part of your code did you think would add a delay?

Comment: @nile - This code is so strange, I think the idea was to start the animation, and use the loading time of the image as the delay.

Answer (score 3):

Add a [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

```
 $(this).delay(4000).animate({opacity: 1}, 4000);
```

I think probably you are confused with delay and duration. The number specified in the animation function is the duration of the animation, for adding a delay just add `.delay()` before animate.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnXEL/)

Comment: i think it's not a problem of adding delay function, animate show image with opacity option after 4000 ms

Comment: @medBo that is animation duration not delay what you are seeing, in which case OPs code is working fine..

Comment: @PSL:I had written px unit with with the value 0 which was making the image display directly as there was no opacity:0 happening. So, it appeared to me that nothing was working.

Comment: @Ak1to SO your issue was not the delay? but your fiddle looked fine?

Comment: It wasn't MY fiddle. While following the code in the fiddle, my wrote opacity:0px; but one shouldn't write the unit when the quantity is 0. This was the reason that my code(that I have written on in the question) does not work.

Answer (score 2):

you have an error here :

```
<img class="delayImg" style="width:156px;margin: 41px 0; height:37px;opacity:0px;" ....
```

--->  **opacity: 0** without px

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/38Afs/) css code , it's :

```
.delayImg {opacity:0;}
```